# I can't cd into a folder that I created a long time ago, and I am the su

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard

I can't cd into a folder that I created, I believe I might have fiddled with chmod I while ago.

Strange if I type: su and my password it says wrong password, although I am the owner of the laptop and have the admin account (there is only 1 account which is mine).

Ideas?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear to me... you can't login as root because you forgot the password, and your can't enter a folder because you're no longer the owner? Is that correct?

Comment: i can login just find, but I can't access a folder on my system when in terminal i.e. cd my_folder/ says access denied.  I am the root user as far as I know!

Comment: get some more data on the folder -- `stat folderName`, match it with your details (`id`) and reconfirm the folder permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click that folder, select *Get Info*, if necessary click the lock to the lower right, and add your user account to the list by clicking the `+` button add the bottom. Make sure your privilege is *Read & Write*, select your user name, click the cogwheel and select *Make username (me) the owner*.

If you took away your *execute* privilege, that might not work though.

---

Alternatively, open Terminal and type

```
sudo chown your_user_shortname /path/to/folder
sudo chmod u+rwx /path/to/folder
```

You can drag&drop the folder onto the Terminal window to keep from having to type the path.

---

`su` requires you to type the *target* user's password (root by default). Try it by typing:

```
su $( whoami )
```

It works after entering your password. root doesn't have a password on OS X to prevent root logins though.

If you're an Administrator (i.e. member of the `wheel` group which is granted `sudo` privileges in `/etc/sudoers`), you need to `sudo` first. Do the following:

```
sudo su
```

This allows you to type *your* account's password and then execute `su` after you get additional privileges from `sudo`.